# Duda con formato Numérico en C#

Tags: c#, windows-forms, .net

tengo una inquietud, tengo un sistema cliente servidor de escritorio en producción. Resulta que al obtener un valor numérico, en los equipos de unos usuarios me arroja el valor para este caso de 70.187.857,00 (Con puntos decimales y comas), para este caso me lo trae como la lógica de negocio lo pide, pero en otro computador de otro usuario lo trae como 70187,857.00

En el código de lo tengo definido de la siguiente manera:

```
Valor = Convert.ToDouble(LineaProy[9],System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);  
Valor.ToString("#,##0.00")
```

Agradecería mucho que alguien me de su punto de vista de que puede estar sucediendo en este caso, ya que solo pasa con el equipo de un usuario en especifico y en los demás todo sale muy bien.

Muchas Gracias.

Comment: Revisa la región del equipo de ese usuario, tal vez tenga región de España (por el cambio entre , y .)

Comment: Ingresa a panel de control, y verifica la configuración regional de los números. Copia los valores de tu equipo en el cual funciona todo correcto y colócalos en el equipo en el que varía el resultado. Saludos.

Comment: el problema se presenta al aplicar el formato con el ToString() o al convertir a numerico con el ToDouble() ? porque no entiendo a que te refieres con el "me lo trae"

Comment: Prueba en el Program.cs a añadir la siguiente linea `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;`. De esta manera estableces `InvariantCulture` para todo el ámbito de la aplicación.